# Proper and improper forcing Stationarity

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, forcing

In his book on Proper and Improper forcing Shelah writes on page 89:

> In Sect. 1 we introduce the property "proper" of forcing notions: preserving
> stationarity not only of subsets of $\omega_1$ but even of any $S \subseteq \cal S_{\leq\aleph_0}(\lambda)$. We then
> prove its equivalence to another formulation.

My question is how $$S\subseteq \cal S_{\leq\aleph_0}(\lambda)$$ is a generalization of $\omega_1$ since $\omega_1$ is uncountable but  $$\cal S_{\leq\aleph_0}(\lambda)$$ are at most countable subsets of $\lambda$.

Also I would like to understand what is $\text{Lim}\bar{Q
}$ on -5th line on that page 89.

Finally, I would like to know what is that **another formulation** in the snippet above.

[image]

Comment: For the first question, $\omega_1$ is also a collection of some countable subsets of $\omega_1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first question, $\omega_1$ is a subset of $[\omega_1]^{<\aleph_1}$ (the set Shelah denotes $\mathcal S_{\le\aleph_0}(\omega_1)$), namely, any countable ordinal is a countable subset of $\omega_1$. You can check that $\omega_1$ is club in $[\omega_1]^{<\aleph_1}$, and that being a stationary subset of $\omega_1$ in the sense of ordinals and in the sense of collections of countable subsets coincide.

For the second question, $\mathrm{Lim}\bar Q$ is the countable support limit of the iteration sequence $\bar Q$. Shelah uses $\mathrm{Lim}_{<\aleph_0}\bar Q$ for the finite support limit. What $\mathrm{Lim}\bar Q$ means (i.e., what kind of supports are being considered) usually depends on context; in the page you quote, it is clear that he means countable supports.

Comment: Could you help me to understand what is a **finite support limit of the iteration sequence $\bar{Q}$**, say ? What piece of data is finite here ?

Comment: The support. This is explained in the text (in Chapter 2; see in particular definition 2.2. in page 58). At a limit stage $\lambda$ in an iteration $(P_\alpha,\dot Q_\alpha:\alpha<\lambda)$, conditions are functions $p$ with domain $\lambda$, with $p_\alpha$ being forced $P_\alpha$ to be in $\dot Q_\alpha$. The support is the collection of $\alpha$ where $P_\alpha$ is not simply the maximal condition ($1_{Q_\alpha}$), There are some wrinkles but that is the basic idea. I would suggest to supplement with Kunen's or Jech's textbooks.